# Jooq not throwing exception for failures

Tags: java, jooq

I am using **Jooq** to populate CSV data into my DB.
If I provide ***"String Value"*** instead of  ***Int***  It is not entering the value into DB but in the mean time it is not throwing the error also.
How do I know if the upload is failed or not.How to handle these type of exceptions.In addition that is there any way to check/throw warning if i try to give string in int column.

version : 3.8.x

```
Connection connection = getConnection()
try(Connection connection = getConnection()) {
            DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);

            create.loadInto(Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP)
                    .loadCSV(new File("/my/folder/testInput.csv"))
                    .fields(Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.PROCESS_QUEUE_ID,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.PROCESS_NAME,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.QUEUE_NAME,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.MARKEPTLACE,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.QUEUE_TYPE,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.CREATED_BY,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.CREATED_TIME,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.LAST_MODIFIED_BY,
                            Tables.PROCESS_QUEUE_MAP.LAST_MODIFIED_TIME)
                    .execute();

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### General failure handling with the `Loader` API

The loader API by default throws all kinds of exceptions that are raised from the underlying database or JDBC driver. This can be configured and overridden by specifying:

- [`LoaderOptionsStep.onErrorAbort()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/LoaderOptionsStep.html#onErrorAbort--) (default)
- [`LoaderOptionsStep.onErrorIgnore()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/LoaderOptionsStep.html#onErrorIgnore--)

This only affects JDBC errors, not data loading "errors"

#### jOOQ's auto-conversion

For historic reason, throughout the jOOQ API, the automatic conversion between data types is "lenient" instead of "fail-fast". All data type conversion passes through the [`Convert`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/Convert.html) utility, which returns `null` in case a data type conversion fails. E.g. when calling [`Convert.convert(Object, Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/Convert.html#convert-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-), the following test will pass:

```
assertNull(Convert.convert("abc", int.class));
```

This has been criticised in the past, but cannot be changed easily in the jOOQ API due to backwards compatibility.

Workarounds include:

- Parsing the CSV content yourself
- Passing an `Object[][]` to [`LoaderSourceStep.loadArrays()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/LoaderSourceStep.html#loadArrays-java.lang.Object:A...-)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the info.I found how to do it from this sample https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-csv/